# How to highlight columns by comparing all models form native in pandas and count

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, data-science

I am trying to compare native column with each model column like -> if native is less than model1 then highlight it , same  if native is less than model 2 then highlight it . and count how many columns are less than native if it is less than 5 then make a new column and put done else put repeat for each row . we are having more than 20k row.

[image]

```
df.style.apply(lambda x: ['background: lightgreen' if x.MODEL 1 <= x.NATIVE    == 1 else '' for i in x], 
               axis=1)
```

THis is just refrence i dont know how do i do it.

Comment: Hi and welcome on SO. It will be great if you can have a look at [ask] and then try to produce a [mcve].

Comment: Likewise, please do not write question titles in ALL CAPS.

Comment: Please don't write normal sentences in all upper-case, not even titles. Writing in all upper-case is considered shouting, and it's very rude to shout at people you want to ask for help.